# Shiny: problems with conditionalPanel based on selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have issues with the following code. My aim is to display some "numericInput" based on a "selectizeInput". It is working but I have 2 issues :

- When no item is selected, there is still a numericInput displayed, when there should be none.
- When no item is selected, the checkboxInput (which behavior should be totally independent from the selectizeInput) is not responding: I can click it, but "TEST" is not printed.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Jérémy

choice_list=letters[1:5]

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(

      selectizeInput("ckbox",label="Letters",
                     choices=setNames(1:length(choice_list),choice_list),
                     selected = 1,multiple=T),

      lapply(1:length(choice_list), function(i) {
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = paste0("input.ckbox.indexOf('",i,"') != -1"),
          numericInput(paste0("numinput",i), choice_list[i], 1)
        )
      }),

      checkboxInput("test", label = "TEST", value = F),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.test",
        h3("TEST")                
      )
    )
  ), server = shinyServer(
    function(input, output, session) {  
    })
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your issues are related to your the condition of your first conditional panel. When the `selectize` element is empty, `input.ckbox` is `null` and you get a JS error when trying to get `indexOf`.

Try this condition:

```
condition = paste0("input.ckbox != null && input.ckbox.indexOf('",i,"') != -1")
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved both issues indeed. Actually i tried this before, but with a single "&", probably because i'm a JS beginner ! Thank you